# Cannot make items (3) to be centered on top of other elements (3), flexbox

Tags: html, css

I am currently in the process of building a community blog/website 
[THPSBlog](http://https//thpsblog.000webhostapp.com)
While using the FlexBox functionality, I split and created a banner into three different sections

```
                          NEWS | MEDIA | COMMUNITY
```

It is a banner that contains 3 icons on top and below you can see 3 boxes of information 
I have tried many combinations of justifying or aligning my content and items, but so far I haven't been able to properly center my three icons while being on top of the information box.

**Banner**

```
#flex-banner {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: baseline;
  background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.308);
}
```

**Icons**

```
.icon {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

**Boxes of information**

```
.box {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
```

Media query for iPhone 6S

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 
    .navbar {
      justify-content: center;
      align-content: flex-start;
      display: flex;
      height: auto;
    }
    .navbar ul {
      display: block;
      width: auto;
    }
    #flex-banner {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: baseline;
      height: 100%;
      width: auto;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <div id="flex-banner">
            <!-- 1ST BOX-->
        <div class="box">
            <img class="icon" src="icon-news.svg" alt="newsicon"/ width="125px">
            <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SNivhvHi-4PjPDy1tob-91HYs3x3R_z9/view">
                <img src="./customlevels-icon.png" width="250px"/></a>
                <h3>100+ Custom Levels in ONE pack</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- 2ND BOX-->
        <div class="box">
            <img class="icon" src="./icon-media.svg" alt="thpsvideoicon" width="90px"/>
                <iframe width="390" height="245" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uvW0lsyttKw"
                frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <h3>Check tLT's pure ownage in their 2015 Team Video</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- 3RD BOX-->
        <div class="box">
            <img class="icon" src="./icon-community.svg" alt="thpscommunity" width="110px"/>
            <a href="http://thpsx.com/cap-contest-8/">
                <img src="./graveyard-scene.jpg" alt="graveyardtheme" width="400px" /></a>
                <h3>Cap Contest #8 Theme: Graveyard</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to display this information correctly, 3 centered icons within the same line and above the other 3 box elements. Also trying this on my iPhone 6S, portrait looks O.K. (it is not centered but displays as a column, which is good) but landscape gets more messy. Cheers!

Comment: The link to your website doesn't help explain what you want. Please include your `HTML` here to make this question [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [THPSBlog](http://https//thpsblog.000webhostapp.com) not working and why are you using `position: absolute` in `#flex-banner` ?

Comment: (https://thpsblog.000webhostapp.com/) it's a free hosting but seems to be working for me on chrome, sorry for that. Used absolute position so it would "stick" to the position of the body, the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. I also would suggest using Bootstrap. It's much more simple to start with. Good luck!

```css
#flex-banner {
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the Bootstrap recommendation, will give it a try! sadly it did not worked :(